# convert javascrip function CryptoJS.HmacSHA256() to apex

Tags: apex, javascript, crypto

I am trying to convert the below javascript code into apex. The javascript code is below-

```
timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
var method = request.method;
var path = request.url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
var prehash = timestamp + '-' + method + '-' + path;
var secret = 'xxxxx';
var username = '';
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(prehash, secret);
```

The hash being generated here looks like -

> 2AE14BDA56ABE98BE42145843796E7D82CE7173993D0F9B19C837127B88D4D08

The apex code is below-

```
string timestmp = String.valueof((DateTime.now().getTime())/1000);
string method ='POST';
string testurl='';
string path = testurl.replace('/^.*\\/\\/[^\\/]+/', '');
string prehash = timestmp + '-' + method + '-' + path;
string secret = 'xxxxx';
string username = '';
String algorithmName='HmacSHA256';
Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(prehash), Blob.valueOf(secret));
string hash = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
```

The hash being generated by apex looks like -

> QR4Z80VYHP0Y1QURWA9KLP3LPB+WJT6LWMP4I4VPR7W=

I want the hash being generated by apex to be similar in format to the hash being generated by javascript. Can anyone pls advice how should I modify my code to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of your JavaScript is hexadecimal text (Base 16). The output of your Apex is Base64.

To generate a hexadecimal string in Apex, use [`EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blob)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) rather than `base64Encode()`.